# How to match single characters in results in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm on at detecting the time conflict but i'm stucked at days conflict. This is my table

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (starttime, endtime, day)
VALUES
    ('09:00:00', '11:00:00', 'MT'), 
    ('10:00:00', '12:00:00', 'M'),
    ('06:00:00', '10:00:00', 'MTW'),
    ('06:00:00', '10:00:00', 'ThFS'),
    ('11:00:00', '12:00:00', 'S'),
    ('15:00:00', '16:00:00', 'F'),
    ('06:00:00', '09:00:00', 'M');
```

and this is the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.starttime,
    t1.endtime,
    t1.day
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON
        (t1.starttime > t2.starttime AND t1.starttime < t2.endtime) OR
        (t1.endtime > t2.starttime   AND t1.endtime < t2.endtime)
WHERE
    t2.starttime IS NOT NULL;
```

the results are

```
    starttime   endtime day
09:00:00    11:00:00    MT
10:00:00    12:00:00    M
06:00:00    10:00:00    MTW
06:00:00    10:00:00    ThFS
11:00:00    12:00:00    S
06:00:00    09:00:00    M
```

that should be

```
    starttime   endtime day
   09:00:00 11:00:00    MT
   10:00:00 12:00:00    M
   06:00:00 10:00:00    MTW
   06:00:00 09:00:00    M
```

I'm trying `MATCH AGAINST` but it doesn't end well. Thanks for the help.
BTW: i tried using LIKE but still doesn't work on MTW and TTh days.

Comment: Awful table design! Normalize your database! Explain day can include serveral weekdays, represented by their first letter(s) to your audience! Split to single day per row and use weekday number instead of weekday name. Add an ID field (integer autoincrement) as primary key. Then you can join on day and filter conflicts.

Comment: Sorry for that table design. I got it somewhere as an example. Thank you for the idea. I will post an update when succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks to BitAccesser. I converted days to numbers then thru php, i used similar_text function to compare the results.